# Session expired message in password protected apps

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat, tomcat7

I've never worked with JSP and tomcat before. I need to install a couple of third-party applications and create a basic authentication for them. I've appended corresponding security constraint tag to WEB-INFO/web.xml file of each application. It works; login credentials and roles are validated properly, however user instantly gets redirected to the "Session expired page. Click here to go back". And only after click on that link user can browse the application.

**server.xml**:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
</Realm>
```

**tomcat-users.xml**:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />
    <role rolename="myuser" />
    <user username="administrator" password="password" roles="manager-gui, myuser" />
    <user username="user1" password="password" roles="myuser" />
</tomcat-users>
```

**web.xml**:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Protected Resources</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>myuser</role-name>
    <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>UserDatabase</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it configuration or application issue?

Comment: It may due to session persistence across restarts [You may want to disable this feature](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence)

Comment: Why would this have to do with session persistence across restarts?